# jQuery - Conditionally execute code based on selected option of a dropdown

Tags: jquery

I am executing some code on change of a dropdown list, depending on what option is selected. Is using `.prop(selectedIndex)` the best way to handle this here?

```
$(document).on('change', '#toggleList', function () {
    if ($(this).prop('selectedIndex') == 0 || $(this).prop('selectedIndex') == 2) {
        //some code
    }
    else if ($(this).prop('selectedIndex') == 1) {
        //some other code
    }
    else {
        //some other code
    }
});
```

Comment: Apart from doing the `$(this).prop('selectedIndex')` only once and saving the result into a variable instead of using JQuery in all if-statements, I think it's fine.

Comment: Apart from what @Danmoreng said you can always use a swhict instead `else if`'s (Imaging that instead of 3 options you have 10 D:) and that this should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why are you basing it on the index? Use `this.value` to get the value of the option.

Comment: @Barmar wouldn't I then be doing a string comparison with the value? is that cleaner?

Comment: What @Barmar said It's really important Index and the Id of the element in most of the cases aren't never gonna be the same!

Comment: @noclist that depends on if your `value` is a text then maybe but if is an integer JavaSctript I'll we take it with no problems. (this depends on a lot of the structure of your HTML code)

Comment: Hard-coding magic numbers like that is almost always wrong. If you change the order of the options you'll have to go through your code fixing it. This is why options have values. What's wrong with comparing strings? It's not like this has to be done millions of times a second, it's only done when the user selects something from a menu. Performance is negligible.

Comment: @Barmar good point, thanks for the input